# Angular 5 change detection on mutable objects

Tags: angular

I know this is a frequent question, but this is more related to Angular 5.
From what I remember this used to work in Angular 2, unless I specify

```
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
```

Code:

```
  addFruit(food) {
    // this is not working
    this.fruits.push(food);

    // this works
    // this.fruits = [...this.fruits, food];
  }
```

Did something changed in Angular 5+ that the first method is no longer working?

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ch-detec?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're displaying the array in the view using `{{ }}`. Angular is checking for change in the `fruits object`. When you push to the array, the reference is the same but in the other method, you changed the reference so it's a new object. Try this in the view :

```
<p *ngFor='let fruit of fruits'>{{ fruit }}</p>
```

Or you can use `json pipe` like this :

```
{{ fruits | json }}
```