# How to listen for value changes from class property TypeScript - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, angular5

In AngularJS, we can listen variable change using `$watch`, `$digest`... which is no longer possible with the new versions of Angular (5, 6).

In Angular, this behaviour is now part of the component lifecycle.

I checked on the official documention, articles and especially on [Angular 5 change detection on mutable objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48446270/angular-5-change-detection-on-mutable-objects), to find out how to listen to a variable (class property) change in a [TypeScript class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) / [Angular](https://angular.io/)

What is proposed today is :

```js
import { OnChanges, SimpleChanges, DoCheck } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp',
  templateUrl: 'my-comp.html',
  styleUrls: ['my-comp.css'],
  inputs:['input1', 'input2']
})
export class MyClass implements OnChanges, DoCheck, OnInit{

  //I can track changes for this properties
  @Input() input1:string;
  @Input() input2:string;
  
  //Properties what I want to track !
  myProperty_1: boolean
  myProperty_2: ['A', 'B', 'C'];
  myProperty_3: MysObject;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  //Solution 1 - fired when Angular detects changes to the @Input properties
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    //Action for change
  }

  //Solution 2 - Where Angular fails to detect the changes to the input property
  //the DoCheck allows us to implement our custom change detection
  ngDoCheck() {
    //Action for change
  }
}
```

This is only true for `@Input()` property !

If I want to track changes of my component's own properties (`myProperty_1`, `myProperty_2` or `myProperty_3`), this will not work.

Can someone help me to solve this problematic ? Preferably a solution that is compatible with Angular 5

Comment: You can use Observable

Comment: Refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41915625/how-to-detect-variable-change-in-angular2

Comment: @Elliott08 In the link that you share, the answer specifies that it should work only if we use `@Input` : ***As to your comment about @Input(), that works well when a parent component-child interaction, so that wouldn't really work for you in this case***

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can still check component's field members value change by `KeyValueDiffers` via `DoCheck` lifehook.

```
import { DoCheck, KeyValueDiffers, KeyValueDiffer } from '@angular/core';

differ: KeyValueDiffer<string, any>;
constructor(private differs: KeyValueDiffers) {
  this.differ = this.differs.find({}).create();
}

ngDoCheck() {
  const change = this.differ.diff(this);
  if (change) {
    change.forEachChangedItem(item => {
      console.log('item changed', item);
    });
  }
}
```

see **[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngdocheck-variable)**.

Comment: this will work, however i would say is not the best solution because that lifeCycle hook runs really often.

Comment: @ValeSteve `DoCheck` only runs after change detection.

Comment: well, if you look into it change detection run pretty often :)

Comment: It seems to me that this solution is the closest to what I want and the most logical that uses the advantages of the Angular framework without reinventing the wheel and rewrite what is already defined by angular. Nevertheless, I am a little confused about the use of ChangeDetectorRef OR DoCkeck! 
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.9/packages/core/src/change_detection/change_detector_ref.ts#L1-L192

Comment: @LyesCHIOUKH `ChangeDetectorRef` let you manually trigger angular's change detection. `DoCheck` is the life hook which will be triggered after change detection. This is their relationship.

Comment: @Pengyy , I have the same concern as of you, also it is recommended not to use it, as far it runs on change detection, its actually listens to all the events even mouse movement.

Comment: Not work in angular 13 !

Answer (score 5):

I think the nicest solution to your issue is to use a decorator that replaces the original field with a property automatically, then on the setter you can create a `SimpleChanges` object similar to the one created by angular in order to use the same notification callback as for angular (alternatively you could create a different interface for these notifications, but the same principle applies)

```
import { OnChanges, SimpleChanges, DoCheck, SimpleChange } from '@angular/core';

function Watch() : PropertyDecorator & MethodDecorator{
    function isOnChanges(val: OnChanges): val is OnChanges{
        return !!(val as OnChanges).ngOnChanges
    }
    return (target : any, key: string | symbol, propDesc?: PropertyDescriptor) => {
        let privateKey = "_" + key.toString();
        let isNotFirstChangePrivateKey = "_" + key.toString() + 'IsNotFirstChange';
        propDesc = propDesc || {
            configurable: true,
            enumerable: true,
        };
        propDesc.get = propDesc.get || (function (this: any) { return this[privateKey] });

        const originalSetter = propDesc.set || (function (this: any, val: any) { this[privateKey] = val });

        propDesc.set = function (this: any, val: any) {
            let oldValue = this[key];
            if(val != oldValue) {
                originalSetter.call(this, val);
                let isNotFirstChange = this[isNotFirstChangePrivateKey];
                this[isNotFirstChangePrivateKey] = true;
                if(isOnChanges(this)) {
                    var changes: SimpleChanges = {
                        [key]: new SimpleChange(oldValue, val, !isNotFirstChange)
                    }
                    this.ngOnChanges(changes);
                }
            }
        }
        return propDesc;
    }
}

// Usage
export class MyClass implements OnChanges {


    //Properties what I want to track !
    @Watch()
    myProperty_1: boolean  =  true
    @Watch()
    myProperty_2 =  ['A', 'B', 'C'];
    @Watch()
    myProperty_3 = {};

    constructor() { }
    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        console.log(changes);
    }
}

var myInatsnce = new MyClass(); // outputs original field setting with firstChange == true
myInatsnce.myProperty_2 = ["F"]; // will be notified on subsequent changes with firstChange == false
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It seems to me that this solution is difficult to implement in the case where we have several class properties to track. 
In case you want to launch an action when two class properties change at the same time, how do you set it up with this solution ?

Comment: @LyesCHIOUKH There could be several ways to do this, two which i an think off the top of my head: The first one is to put the notification on a timer, and not fire it immediately. Another one is to batch notifications explicitly using some method call. I could change the sample to us either version, the first one would be simpler to implement. Are you interested in either solution ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What do you think of the solution that combines KeyValueDiffer + DoCheck proposed by #Pengyy ?

Comment: @LyesCHIOUKH It seems to work fine, and it seems to be a more Angular way of doing things which in your case is probably the better option. My solution would also work pretty much the same outside angular :).

Comment: Thank you @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir. Actually, I will opt for the solution that adapts best with Angular :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir can you create one without being depended on angular?

Answer (score 3):

as said you can use

```
public set myProperty_2(value: type): void {
 if(value) {
  //doMyCheck
 }

 this._myProperty_2 = value;
}
```

and then if you need to retrieve it

```
public get myProperty_2(): type {
  return this._myProperty_2;
}
```

in that way you can do all the checks that you want while setting/ getting your variables such this methods will fire every time you set/get the myProperty_2 property.

small demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n72qlu

Comment: This solution works, but it is not optimal. Just for example, imagine that we want to track two variables change to trigger an action! It will be more complicated to set up..

Comment: In that way unfortunately you have to use the doCheck offered by angular

Answer (score 3):

I think I came into the way to listen to DOM changes that you can get any changes that do to your element, I really hope these hints and tips will help you to fix your problem, following the following simple step:

**First**, you need to reference your element like this:

in HTML:

```
<section id="homepage-elements" #someElement>
....
</section>
```

And in your TS file of that component:

```
@ViewChild('someElement')
public someElement: ElementRef;
```

**Second**, you need to create an observer to listen to that element changes, you need to make your component `ts` file to `implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy`, then implement that `ngAfterViewInit()` there (`OnDestroy` has a job later):

```
private changes: MutationObserver;
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  console.debug(this.someElement.nativeElement);

  // This is just to demo 
  setInterval(() => {
    // Note: Renderer2 service you to inject with constructor, but this is just for demo so it is not really part of the answer
    this.renderer.setAttribute(this.someElement.nativeElement, 'my_custom', 'secondNow_' + (new Date().getSeconds()));
  }, 5000);

  // Here is the Mutation Observer for that element works
  this.changes = new MutationObserver((mutations: MutationRecord[]) => {
      mutations.forEach((mutation: MutationRecord) => {
        console.debug('Mutation record fired', mutation);
        console.debug(`Attribute '${mutation.attributeName}' changed to value `, mutation.target.attributes[mutation.attributeName].value);
      });
    }
  );

  // Here we start observer to work with that element
  this.changes.observe(this.someElement.nativeElement, {
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    characterData: true
  });
}
```

You will see the console will work with any changes on that element:

[image]

This is another example here that you will see 2 mutation records fired and for the class that changed:

```
// This is just to demo
setTimeout(() => {
   // Note: Renderer2 service you to inject with constructor, but this is just for demo so it is not really part of the answer
  this.renderer.addClass(this.someElement.nativeElement, 'newClass' + (new Date().getSeconds()));
  this.renderer.addClass(this.someElement.nativeElement, 'newClass' + (new Date().getSeconds() + 1));
}, 5000);

// Here is the Mutation Observer for that element works
this.changes = new MutationObserver((mutations: MutationRecord[]) => {
    mutations.forEach((mutation: MutationRecord) => {
      console.debug('Mutation record fired', mutation);
      if (mutation.attributeName == 'class') {
        console.debug(`Class changed, current class list`, mutation.target.classList);
      }
    });
  }
);
```

Console log:

[image]

And just housekeeping stuff, `OnDestroy`:

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.changes.disconnect();
}
```

Finally, you can look into this Reference: [Listening to DOM Changes Using MutationObserver in Angular](http://nitayneeman.com/posts/listening-to-dom-changes-using-mutationobserver-in-angular/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It seems, to me, that this solution is difficult to implement in the case where we have several class properties to track!

Comment: @LyesCHIOUKH you can filter the property you want and add observable to each property if you want to track each one alone, this is just hinting or tip to start with.

as for example `... mutations.filter((mutation: MutationRecord) => mutation.attributeName == 'myProperty1').forEach( ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can import ChangeDetectorRef

```
 constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
          // detect changes on the current component
            // this.cd is an injected ChangeDetector instance
            this.cd.detectChanges();

            // or run change detection for the all app
            // this.appRef is an ApplicationRef instance
            this.appRef.tick();
}
```