# Angular 2+ detect object property change inside service

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6, angular-services, key-value-observing

Let's say we have a service like this one:

```
SupermanService {
  private _superman: Hero;
  public supermanReplaced = new EventEmitter<Hero>();
  public supermanPropertyUpdated = new EventEmitter<Hero>();

  public get superman(): Hero {
    return this._superman;
  }

  public set superman(superman): void {
    this._superman = superman;
    this.supermanReplaced.emit(superman);
  }

  public updateSupermanProperty(key: string, val: string | number): Hero {
    this._superman[key] = val;
    this.supermanPropertyUpdated.emit(superman);
    return this._superman;
  }

}
```

Is there some way to detect `supermanPropertyUpdated` without using the `updateSupermanProperty()` function but by e.g. setting `this.superman.power = 10`?

I found some posts that suggest the [KeyValueDiffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49552258/how-to-listen-for-value-changes-from-class-property-typescript-angular/49552990#49552990) in combination with the `DoCheck` hook, but that is not available for services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **get/set** methods.

In your example:

```
class SupermanService {
  private _superman: Hero;
  public supermanReplaced = new EventEmitter<Hero>();
  public supermanPropertyUpdated = new EventEmitter<Hero>();

  public set power(level: integer) {
    this._superman.power = level;
    this._supermanPropertyUpdated.emit(this._superman);
  }

  public get superman(): Hero {
    return this._superman;
  }

  public set superman(superman: Hero): void {
    this._superman = superman;
    this.supermanReplaced.emit(superman);
  }

  public updateSupermanProperty(key: string, val: string | number): Hero {
    this._superman[key] = val;
    this._supermanPropertyUpdated.emit(superman);
    return this._superman;
  }

}
```

After this you can use:

```
SupermanService.power = 10;
```

and all the listeners will be notified

**Update**

Another implementation to solve this problem is modifying your **Hero** class adding a public **EventEmitter property** and subscribing to this from your service. Assign a setter for each property on your **Hero** class and emit the change like **Output** and in your service you can emit the changes.

```
class Hero {

    public onPropertyChange = new EventEmitter<Hero>();
    private _name: string;

    get name(): string {
        return this._name;
    }

    set name(value: string) {
        this._name = value;
        this.onPropertyChange.emit(this);
    }
}

class SupermanService {
  private _superman: Hero;
  public supermanReplaced = new EventEmitter<Hero>();

  public get superman(): Hero {
    return this._superman;
  }

  public set superman(superman: Hero): void {
    this._superman = superman;
    this.supermanReplaced.emit(superman);
  }

  public get supermanPropertyUpdated(): EventEmitter<Hero> {
    return this._superman.onPropertyChange;
  }
}
```

Comment: It wont notify by changing like this: `SupermanService.superman.power = 10`. It's just a getter on which you directly change it's property (no setter).

Comment: I added an Update, you need a code example or I explain myself :)?

Comment: hmmm that's very similar to the `updateSupermanProperty()` function right?

`supermanPropertyUpdated` won't be emitted in case the `superman` properties itself are getting updated.

Comment: For the updated implementation you do not need `updateSupermanProperty` I'll add the example

Comment: I added the new example @ritaj

Comment: It should be but @sevic asked the question.