# How to listen to a property in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, properties

I have doubt in angular. How to listen to the property value changes in the same class.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})

export class AppComponent  { 
  name:string
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do. please explain your problem

Comment: You can use typescript setters and getters to do something when the property change.

Comment: I think ngOnChanges is for only Input property.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49552258/how-to-listen-for-value-changes-from-class-property-typescript-angular

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to act upon a property change in your case, is to implement getters and setters for your property.

**Example:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})

export class AppComponent  { 
  private _name: string

  set name(data) {
    this._name = data;

    // here you can trigger something on data change
    // do something when data is assigned to name
  }

  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }

  //another example for setters as @Input properties
  //here you will act if the component receives input change
  //from a parent component
  @Input
  set name(data: any) {
    this._name = data;

    // here you can trigger something on data change
    // do something when data is assigned to name
  }
}
```